# Getting Locations Best Practice

Tags: codenameone

What are the best practices one needs to know when trying to get the most accurate location coordinates from a user.

How can I explicitly get location using the user's gps? How can I also ensure getting location using the network is accurate? I am asking because when I get location while I am home..by the time I get to the office, the location I get is still the same which isnt supposed to be so. Does it have to do with  my listener?

Any help/code snippets will be appreciated.

Salam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modern Android devices and all iOS devices don't use GPS as much as they use hybrid location. Hybrid location correlates all sensor information (including gps) to give a location as accurately and quickly as possible while reducing battery usage.

This is on by default in Codename One if you don't do anything like explicitly specifying that Google Play Services shouldn't be included or if you include google play services other than location (without including location via the build hint `android.playService.location=true`) this won't be used either. In those cases Android will fallback to use GPS which is slower.

You can read more about build hints [here](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html).

Notice that even then getting location takes time so make a request so you should use the `getCurrentLocationSync()` method or the location listener API to make sure you get a more accurate reading.